# Do flags in private beta age out?

Tags: support, flagging

I have several flags of varying types that have been sitting around for a while... the oldest unmanaged one from April 26th...

Will these flags be held in limbo until we have mods to handle them or will they have to be re-raised because they get ignored?

I know that flags **have** been being managed because I have a couple of older ones that were marked as helpful and they were for things like comments, which don't go into queues the way some flags do.

I appreciate that the CMs are likely very busy with all sorts of stuff and some of the flag issues are minor but it's a bit disheartening to be trying to use the site as designed and be thwarted.

So, if the flags aren't going to be handled, could we at least "freeze" them until we have mods so that they don't have to be raised again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System flags do not age away (yet... I've suggested getting smarter about this). Flags suggesting closure *do* age away (just like voting to close), but for the most part, system flags remain in the queue until either someone handles them or another action renders them obsolete (e.g. someone deletes a post which may remove outstanding comment flags).

So how do flags get handled during the private beta?

Ideally flags are handled by moderators elected by the community. But until this community grows large enough to hold proper elections, the Stack Exchange Community Team will be appointing provisional moderators to take on those responsibilities (typically a few weeks after the site enters public beta). In the meantime, I generally take on those Moderator responsibilities until the provisional moderators can be appointed.

But my function is *not* to run your site. My role is to help get this site started and offer my guidance regarding best practices for community building to establish a foundation for taking on these responsibilities yourselves.

So when it comes to flag handling, I will general handle immediate administrative issues that have some degree of urgency. I will also (generally) handle flags that have an obvious outcome. But when a flag/issue can wait (or needs a judgement call about what is needed), I generally prefer to leave those for the up-and-coming moderators who will actually represent the interests of the community as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When trying to research this, I ran into [this Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278076/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-as-flags-remain-pending-and-or-age-away) question and I think I was confusing close flags (which I think **do** age out?) and the other types of flags... which it sounds like they do not... Is that correct?

Comment: @Catija I hadn't noticed that feature was implemented. Yes, flags suggesting closure do age away just a close votes do. I updated the post.